# How to change previous and current row value to 1 based on current value at each index

Tags: python

I want to replace 1 where x is present in each row and its previous x-1 rows at each index wherever that number (x) is present.

```
df = {1: [1,0,0,0,0], 2: [0,2,0,0,0],3:[0,0,3,0,0],4:[0,0,0,0,0],5:[0,0,0,0,5]} 

randomdf = pd.DataFrame(df)  
randomdf
```

PS. There are many such 2's ,3's in those respective columns, and i have shared a sample df for clarity

Input:-

Here x can be 1,2,3,4 or 5
so if x = 5 , i want to replace 5 with 1 and also i want to insert 1 in previous x-1 rows i.e ( previous 4 rows) as shown in required output.

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   2   0   0   0
2   0   0   3   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   5
```

required output:-

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   1   1   1   0   1
1   0   1   1   0   1
2   0   0   1   0   1
3   0   0   0   0   1
4   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: what type of structure is that in your python code ? string, list, ... ?

Comment: dataadas = {1: [1,0,0,0,0], 2: [0,2,0,0,0],3:[0,0,3,0,0],4:[0,0,0,0,0],5:[0,0,0,0,5]} 

randomdf = pd.DataFrame(dataadas)  
randomdf

Answer (score 0):

First change all non-zero values to 1, then use `replace`

```
df = {1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 3: [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
      4: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[df != 0] = 1
df = df.replace(to_replace=0, method='bfill')
```

```
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  0  1
1  0  1  1  0  1
2  0  0  1  0  1
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: thanks but there is one more point, there are many such 2's in 2nd column at gap of random rows i.e 

df = {1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 3: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      4: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], 5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

and i want to replace 0's with 1 in previous 1 row when the number is 2, previous 2 rows when the number is 3 and on.